# 48-bit colours?

Tags: colors, xorg

Quite often, especially in X11-related things (X resources, Roxterm themes, etc) I see colours specified as 48-bit numbers: `#2e2e34343636`, `#cccc00000000` instead of the usual 24-bit `#2e3436` and `#cc0000`. What are the extra bits used for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer in Xlib documentation under "Color strings". It seems that Xlib actually uses 16 bit RGB values for colors:

> #### [RGB Device String Specification](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#RGB_Device_String_Specification)
>
> [...] an older syntax for RGB Device is supported, but its continued use is not encouraged. The syntax is an initial sharp sign character followed by a numeric specification, in one of the following formats:
>
> ```
> #RGB          (4 bits each)
> #RRGGBB       (8 bits each)
> #RRRGGGBBB    (12 bits each)
> #RRRRGGGGBBBB (16 bits each)
> ```
>
> The R, G, and B represent single hexadecimal digits. When fewer than 16 bits each are specified, they represent the most significant bits of the value (unlike the “rgb:” syntax, in which values are scaled). For example, the string “`#3a7`” is the same as “`#3000a0007000`”.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to X11's use of them, but generally: additional color values which cannot be produced at lesser bit depths and alpha channels.

Answer (score 1):

From the examples you give they are not being used at all since the 24 bit value is simply being repeated (a bit like the practice of using only 3 hex characters to represent "websafe" colours so #c00 means the same as #cc0000 or 204,0,0, extended to #cccc00000000).

32-bit values would usually use the last byte for alpha channel (transparency). I guess it's possible that the 48-bit values are using 24-bit colours with an independent alpha per colour, but the examples you give don't support this.