# How do twelve-character color codes work?

Tags: colors, hexadecimal, rgb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [48-bit colours?](https://superuser.com/questions/122114/48-bit-colours)

I'm using the Xfce 4.10 desktop environment on Ubuntu 12.04. While trying to get things the way I want I came across **#aaaaaaaaaaaa** and **#666666666666** in `~/.config/Terminal/terminalrc`.

> [Configuration]
>
> ColorForeground=**#aaaaaaaaaaaa**
>
> lines deleted ...
>
> ColorCursor=**#666666666666**
>
> FontName=Monospace 11

Looking [elsewhere](http://h30097.www3.hp.com/docs/base_doc/DOCUMENTATION/V40F_HTML/AQ917BTE/DOCU_017.HTM), for example, I see more complex codes like the ones in bold below:

> ! Active border colors
>
> Mwm*activeBackground: **#9851785167AD**
>
> Mwm*activeTopShadowColor: **#AF4199C18E2E**
>
> Mwm*activeBottomShadowColor: **#529737652849**

I know about the 6-character hex code and the RGB code from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp) but I hope someone here can explain the basis of these twelve-character color codes or point me to some easy reading on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Xlib documentation, section "Color strings", mentions this. It seems that Xlib actually uses 16 bit RGB values (CSS is limited to 8 bits, and just happens to use a similar syntax).

> #### [RGB Device String Specification](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#RGB_Device_String_Specification)
>
> [...] an older syntax for RGB Device is supported, but its continued use is not encouraged. The syntax is an initial sharp sign character followed by a numeric specification, in one of the following formats:
>
> ```
> #RGB          (4 bits each)
> #RRGGBB       (8 bits each)
> #RRRGGGBBB    (12 bits each)
> #RRRRGGGGBBBB (16 bits each)
> ```
>
> The R, G, and B represent single hexadecimal digits. When fewer than 16 bits each are specified, they represent the most significant bits of the value (unlike the “rgb:” syntax, in which values are scaled). For example, the string “`#3a7`” is the same as “`#3000a0007000`”.